# Storing stats in the DB or computing them at runtime?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an application where users's activity will be rewarded with points.
There will be a points chart that will assign a certain amount of points for certain action.

My question is which approach is better and most importantly why?

**Approach 1**:
- create a userPoints table in mysql and insert points there at each user action. When the user goes to their profile, query the database for the number of points and display them.

*example:*
user buys an item
query the database: insert 5 points in userPoints for user 2
user follows a place
query the database: insert 7 points in userPoints for user 2
user sells their item
query the database insert -5points in userPoints for user 2

**Approach 2**:
- do not store the points in a table, but count the number of actions user has completed (get their count and type from the db) and then multiply by the certain amount of points for each type of action all at runtime, whenever number of points is required (for example when they visit their profile)

*example*:
user visits their profile to see how many points they have
query the database and count items possessed, places followed, friendships and then multiply items count x5, followings count x7 and friendships count x10 and display the number

**EDIT for Steven:**

let me get this straight, is this the chronology of actions I am supposed to take? How can I tighten this up and reduce the number of queries?

- buying an item has an actionId of 1 and points rewarded are 5 (this is specified in the - actions table in the db)
- Kylie (user ID: 1) buys an item.
- Query DB: Add the item to userItems table for user ID1
- Query DB: Register an action in the userActions table - userId: 1, actionId: 1
- Query DB SET userPointsTotal = userPointsTotal + points rewarded (nest two queries in one like this: set userPointsTotal = userPointsTotal + (select points from actions where actuionid= 1))
- Query DB get userPointsTotal and display value at Kylie's profile
- In the future, refer table userActions so user can get status title, depending on certain type of activity (social status or possessions status)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to store:

1. **Actions** - A table listing actions and the points defined for each.  This will act as your domain table.
2. **User Actions** - A composite-key table (user_id, action_id) listing the actions the user completed AND the points they were awarded (you'll want to store this here in case an action's point value changes after the user completed it.  At any time you can do SUM(user_actions.points) to get an accurate total of the points a user has earned.
3. **User Total** - A value enumerating the total of the points a user has earned.  You can make this a column on the Users table that you update when recording a user's action, or this can be a sum of user_actions.points that's stored in a user index or cache somewhere that gets updated periodically (e.g. Solr, Memcached).  This will allow you to display large numbers of aggregate figures without pounding your database with expensive aggregate functions every time you display a user list.

This gives you the best of all worlds.  You have a quick way of saying how many points a user earned, a reliable method for recalculating totals if they "stray", and a domain table for referential integrity / additional information.

Comment: so Actions is a table, called userActions? And in it, there are fields actionId, actionName, pointsAwarded? And then userActions is a table that says user 1 did action 2? And then userTotal is another table that says user 1, and then what? Im getting confused at this last one (given my other suppositions are right)

Comment: No, Actions would simply be called "Actions".  You have User Actions right.  UserTotal could just be a column on the Users table, or in a denormalized index for a search service like Solr.

Comment: I've updated my question so you can confirm that I've gotten this right?

Comment: Yeah, that looks great.  You may also want to add a cron job that runs every day that recalculates all users' totals, so that if they get out of whack, they'll be automatically fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a hybrid approach. If you strictly store points in the table, it will be very easy to lose track of who has which points for what reason. Alternatively, recalculating them constantly will bring down your server in no time if your user base grows. If you instead, recalculate points every 5 minutes, 1 hour, 12 hours, or whatever interval works for you, and store the results in the userPoints table, you can have fast access speed since you are just looking up a table. Also, if you happen to miscalculate points or mess up in the logic you use to calculate points, you can easily fix your code and re-calculate.

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of points can be thought of as an *aggregate* function based on the individual actions, the question boils down to a decision on when to use pre-aggregation.

Both approaches are valid under different circumstances:

- When computing an aggregate requires very little work, or when the aggregation is not computed often, using pre-aggregation increases complexity, and may even decrease performance, so storing the "raw events" is preferable.
- When computing an aggregate requires going through large volumes of data, or when aggregation is requested very often, pre-aggregation becomes a valid way of improving performance.

Note that databases help you with pre-aggregation: if you define indexes on the action table, and then query for counts and totals instead of the individual actions (i.e. do it the way that you suggested in approach 2 of your question) then the DB will use the data from the index to obtain the counts without actually doing the counting. This gives you performance similar to that of the first approach, with the RDBMS doing most of the work for you.